# JavaFx - prevent UI from hanging while waiting on a timeout from InetAddress

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency

My JavaFX program has a list a of IP addresses in a ListView, I want to loop through each of these addresses periodically and call [INetAddress.isReachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)) on each one. The problem is each call has a timeout associated, meaning the program hangs while waiting on the timeout for an unavailable address. The natural solution to this is threading, however I cant figure out a way that stops the UI from hanging. I have tried [JavaFx's concurrent package](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) and I have tried a Timer Task running on a Timer in a new Thread. I feel I am missing something obvious here.

using JavaFX concurrency:

```
Task task = new Task() {
    @Override
    protected Object call() throws Exception {
        while(true) {
            checkEachIP();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
};

new Thread (task).start();
```

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate to employ Executors Framework. (I have no experience with JavaFX though.)
This way each check could be a separate task.

Comment: This seems to be a decent intro: http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/

Comment: What is `checkEachIP()` doing?

Comment: I'm actually forcing an update of each cell in the ListView to call a custom callback that makes the text colour of each cell red or green depending on the boolean return from INetAddress.isReachable(). figured i'd leave that out as it seemed unnecessary to the question - Also felt horrible checking the ip through the update call of each cell, but couldn't think of a different way to do it.

Comment: OK, but what is `checkEachIP()` doing in terms of threading? Since you're calling it from a background thread, you obviously can't update the cell (however you are doing that) from the current thread the method is called on; so you must be delegating code back to the UI thread somewhere in there. Anyway, it sounds like you already know you are approaching this the wrong way - you should probably fix the underlying problems first (i.e. you should be updating the model, not the cells, and let the cells observe the model).

Comment: Also: *"It seemed unnecessary to the question."* Clearly the code you posted is not causing the UI to hang, so it must be due to some code you haven't posted. You should create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Restructured the app, and as such closing the question. Still havent figured the threading part, but there are other bigger issues to address first, may come back later to ask a better structured question if i still cant figure it out.

Answer (score -3):

If you just want the task to run in the background:

Change:

```
new Thread (task).start();
```

To:

```
Thread thread = new Thread (task);
thread.setDaemon(true); // will run in the background
thread.start();
```

Comment: That's incorrect. The only difference between a daemon thread and a non-daemon thread is that the former does not prevent the jvm from shutting down when it's running.